# Animate SVG path for different screen sizes

Tags: css, animation, svg

I am new to SVG. I am trying to animate a straight line to curved line. I have followed a few links but could not find an appropriate way to do that. Following is my code:

```
<svg width="100%" height="960px">
    <path id="shape" d="M0 0 C0 0, 0 00, 400 0" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="1" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke">
    <animate  
             attributeName="d"
             dur="500ms"
             begin="indefinite"
             repeatCount="1"
             to = "M0 0 C0 0, 165 50, 400 0"
             id="test" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

I also have used:

```
values="M0 0 C0 0, 0 00, 400 0; M M0 0 C0 0, 165 50, 400 0;"
```

in `animate` tag, but still it didn't work.

**What is problem: I am not able to make path curved, animation happens once and then path becomes straight again and I am not sure how to make the same curve on different screen sizes.**

Comment: This code does not work in my browser (Chrome 40 on Mac OS X 10.11).  Here is a demo that does work on mine but probably does not work entirely as you need it to (responsiveness is missing), but it could be a good demo for others to work off of if they too cannot get it to work right away. http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/ovem2zdp/

Answer (score 0):

If you use begin="indefinite" the animation won't start, except via javascript. In order to demonstrate things I've set begin="1s"

If you want the animation to stay in the end position then add fill="freeze" to it.

If you want it to work with different screen sizes, use a viewBox.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="960px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path id="shape" d="M0 0 C0 0, 0 00, 400 0" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="1" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke">
    <animate  
             attributeName="d"
             dur="500ms"
             begin="1s"
             repeatCount="1"
             fill="freeze"
             to = "M0 0 C0 0, 165 50, 400 0"
             id="test" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: It works like a charm! One thing, the curve starts from starting point of the line.. it is not getting pulled from the center.. can we do that?

Comment: Ask another question describing clearly what you want to happen.

Comment: There's no limit on questions and I've answered this one as asked. That's the way it works here. It's a question and answer site, not a forum with continuous discussions. I don't know what you mean by "not getting pulled from the centre", nor do I know where the curve should start from if it's not "the starting point of the line"

Comment: dude, you don't understand sarcasm :P :D